# Validate OAuth 2 Access Token for Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Following this [Browser Based OAuth](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#browser-based-apps) when the request comes back to my site,
`https://oauth2client.com/cb#token=ACCESS_TOKEN`, how do I validate that the access token is real to let them into the application?

Does the web application server do a request to the oauth2server to prove the user hasn't just faked an access token?

Using the `System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule` does it do a request to get the user Claims? I just need to know the Claims of the user are real, and don't need access resources from the OAuth server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit grant OAuth flow is typically used by HTML5/JS Single Page Apps that make AJAX calls directly to WebAPIs, using the access token that they receive over the fragment.

The JavaScript app doesn't need to validate the token - the WebAPI that it calls must. The WebAPI (if written in .net) can use the [JWT Token Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or the new OWIN framework (a sample is here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-DotNet).

If your WebAPI technology doesn't have a JWT token handler available and you need to hand wiring the handling, make sure to validate:

1. Audience of the token (the token has been issued for your API)
2. Issuer of the token (the token has been issued by the trusted authority for the resource)
3. Signature of the token (the token has indeed been signed by the issuer - validate using the public key of the token signing key published by the issuer)
4. The token hasn't expired
5. OAuth Scope (scp)
6. then validate other claims that you base your authorization on