# Azure AD - Validate Token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

Is there any way to validate token of Azure Active Directory using HttpClient in C# just like Facebook is providing?

Facebook Method to validate token:

```
string verifyTokenEndPoint = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={0}&access_token={1}", authToken, appToken);
```

Same way I am looking for the Azure Active Directory, May be with GraphApi or Alternate way?

Please help me out !!

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598835/validate-oauth-2-access-token-for-login?

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it. It's not the endpoint based means I need a endpoint where I can pass token with require information and it gives me result of validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no HTTP endpoint for validating JWTs issued by Azure AD. Instead, you need to use the [JSON Web Token Handler SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065(v=vs.110).aspx) from the Azure AD team (or the equivalent for other platforms).

Sample code here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation